# jQuery mobile move position of a listview

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following and I am trying to animate this so that it will move left from it's position so I am trying:

```
<ul id ="bla" data-role="listview" data-inset="true"><li>bla</li></ul>
$("#bla").animate({left:"200px"},{duration:"slow"});
```

but it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you insert your JQuery code on page load event handler?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#bla").animate({left:"200px"},{duration:"slow"});
});
```

**EDIT** : You also have to change your HTML;

```
<ul id ="bla" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" style="position:relative;"><li>bla</li></ul>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Here is working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/b7HJf/2/

Hope this helps.